# converting a backtrace to a function name

Tags: ios, debugging, xamarin

I've got an iOS application that is generating exceptions from a background thread somewhere. I only know about the exceptions because they are being captured by analytics. Presently, there isn't anything in the UI or user experience that I can match to these crashes.

I've got a stack trace, and I'm trying to figure out how to convert what I believe to be an address and an offset to a function name. My hope is that knowing where the app is making the transition from app code to OS code will help me identify what call is associated with the crash.

from an iOS 16.7.1 iPad Mini I get the following trace.

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib  0x2058f2000 + 30072
libsystem_c.dylib       0x1ce73f000 + 119160
MyApplication           0x102ec8000 + 21342492
MyApplication           0x102ec8000 + 21292032
MyApplication           0x102ec8000 + 21292180
MyApplication           0x102ec8000 + 21292248
MyApplication           0x102ec8000 + 19825180
MyApplication           0x102ec8000 + 20800632
MyApplication           0x102ec8000 + 20800252
libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x22660e000 + 5816
```

Is there some way to figure out the name of the function call identified by that second line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually addresses given in this form:  0x2058f2000 + 30072 the hex number is the load address of the library in this run of the program. and the one after the `+` is the offset of the symbol from that load address.

Every time you rerun an app on iOS all the libraries load at different addresses, but they load rigidly, so even though the load address might change, the offset to a given symbol from the new load address will be the same.

So you can just rerun your app in the debugger, stop somewhere after all the binaries get loaded, then use the

```
(lldb) image list <libraryname>
```

command to get the load address of the library the symbol was from.  Then add the symbol offset to the current load address, and use

```
(lldb) image lookup -va <resultant address>
```

to tell you the symbol.